# Errors in Connecting Microsoft Access with Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm connecting the Microsoft Access with the Visual Basic. There is a problem with the OleDb connection and a problem with the .NET Framework Data Provider for OleDb, I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 now in my Visual Basic, and my desktop's framework is 4.0.30319, I only can find my .NET Data Provider for Oracle and SQL in the registry editor of my desktop.

Are there any solutions for these errors? 
Can I know that are there any website/ways can download the .NET Data Provider for OleDb? Your answers are much appreciated.

Here are some codes in my machine.config files:

```
<connectionStrings >

        <add
            name = "" [String, Required, Collection Key]
            connectionString = "" [String, Required]
            providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" [String]
        />

    </connectionStrings>
-->
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data 
source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated 
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User 
Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>


<system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" 
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc" 
type="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory, System.Data, Version=4.0.30319, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" 
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for OleDb" 
type="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory, System.Data, Version=4.0.30319, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" 
invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data 
Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, 
System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.30319, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" 
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" 
type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, 
Version=4.0.30319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add name="SQL Server Compact Edition Data Provider" 
invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe" description=".NET Framework Data 
Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition" 
type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, 
System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" 
invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data 
Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, 
System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>

</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Error 1: The connection properties object must be of type OleDB Access Connection Properties.

Error 2: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Comment: I think your connection string for the access oledb needs to be updated to correct format 
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword; 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score 0):

There is alot going on in your config 
For a troubleshooting, I might recommend backing up the original and starting fresh

There is an oledb for access (2010) here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

A few other options Trying the ODBC Or using the Microsoft.Jet

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=; Password=;

Comment: That link is for OleDb provider for Sql Server. The OP is trying to connect to Access.

Comment: I think I got caught up with the connection string again... doesnt reference access db from what I can see. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255